# Restarting an app as administrator that uses mutex

Tags: c#, .net, mutex

I have an application that uses a mutex to stop multiple instances running at the same time, and to accept command line inputs in to the running instance.

I have a function in the app that asks the user if they want to restart as admin when required. For example the features they have enabled might require admin rights.

The mutex class looks like this:

```
namespace SingleInstanceClassLibrary
{
/// <summary>
/// Enforces single instance for an application.
/// </summary>
public class SingleInstance : IDisposable
{
    private Mutex mutex = null;
    private Boolean ownsMutex = false;
    private Guid identifier = Guid.Empty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Enforces single instance for an application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="identifier">An identifier unique to this application.       </param>

    public SingleInstance(Guid identifier)
    {
        this.identifier = identifier;
        mutex = new Mutex(true, identifier.ToString(), out ownsMutex);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicates whether this is the first instance of this application.
    /// </summary>
    public Boolean IsFirstInstance
    { get { return ownsMutex; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Passes the given arguments to the first running instance of the     application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arguments">The arguments to pass.</param>
    /// <returns>Return true if the operation succeded, false otherwise.    </returns>

    public Boolean PassArgumentsToFirstInstance(String[] arguments)
    {
        if (IsFirstInstance)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This is the first instance.");

        try
        {
            using (NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream(identifier.ToString()))
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(client))
            {
                client.Connect(200);

                foreach (String argument in arguments)
                    writer.WriteLine(argument);
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        { } //Couldn't connect to server
        catch (IOException)
        { } //Pipe was broken

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Listens for arguments being passed from successive instances of the applicaiton.
    /// </summary>
    public void ListenForArgumentsFromSuccessiveInstances()
    {
        if (!IsFirstInstance)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This is not the first instance.");
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ListenForArguments));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Listens for arguments on a named pipe.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state">State object required by WaitCallback delegate.</param>
    private void ListenForArguments(Object state)
    {
        try
        {
            using (NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream(identifier.ToString()))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server))
            {
                server.WaitForConnection();

                List<String> arguments = new List<String>();
                while (server.IsConnected)
                    arguments.Add(reader.ReadLine());

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(CallOnArgumentsReceived), arguments.ToArray());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        { } //Pipe was broken
        finally
        {
            ListenForArguments(null);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calls the OnArgumentsReceived method casting the state Object to String[].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="state">The arguments to pass.</param>
    private void CallOnArgumentsReceived(Object state)
    {
        OnArgumentsReceived((String[])state);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Event raised when arguments are received from successive instances.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ArgumentsReceivedEventArgs> ArgumentsReceived;
    /// <summary>
    /// Fires the ArgumentsReceived event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="arguments">The arguments to pass with the ArgumentsReceivedEventArgs.</param>
    private void OnArgumentsReceived(String[] arguments)
    {
        if (ArgumentsReceived != null)
            ArgumentsReceived(this, new ArgumentsReceivedEventArgs() { Args = arguments });
    }

    #region IDisposable
    private Boolean disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (mutex != null && ownsMutex)
            {
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                mutex = null;
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~SingleInstance()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I call it like this:

```
private static void Main()
    {
        Guid guid = new Guid("{6EAE2E61-E7EE-42bf-8EBE-BAB890C5410F}");



        //SingleInstance ensures only 1 instance of the app runs at one time. If another instance is started
        //it will be closed. If the 2nd instance included arguments these will be passed to 
        //the singleInstance_ArgumentsReceived event for originally running process
        using (SingleInstance singleInstance = new SingleInstance(guid))
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToString());
            //if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("RunAsAdmin"))

                //MessageBox.Show("YES");

            if (singleInstance.IsFirstInstance || Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Contains("RunAsAdmin"))
            {                 
                singleInstance.ArgumentsReceived += singleInstance_ArgumentsReceived;
                singleInstance.ListenForArgumentsFromSuccessiveInstances();

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

                // Show the system tray icon.                   
                //using (ProcessIcon pi = new ProcessIcon())
                using (ProcessIcon pi = new ProcessIcon())
                {
                    //Use to pass instance of ProcessIcon to LyncPresenceSwitcher
                    lyncPresenceSwitcher.processIcon = pi;

                    //Pass Lync instance
                    pi.lync = lyncClientController;

                    pi.Display();

                    // Make sure the application runs!
                    Application.Run();
                }
            }
            else
                singleInstance.PassArgumentsToFirstInstance(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
        }
    }

    //Process arguments past with app execution
    private static void singleInstance_ArgumentsReceived(object sender, ArgumentsReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (settingsBox == null)
            return;

        foreach (String arg in e.Args)
        {
            //if arguments include OpenSettings open SettingsBox
            if (arg == "OpenSettings")
            {
                settingsBox.ShowDialog();
            }

            if (arg == "RunAsAdmin")
            {
                //singleInstance.Dispose();

            }

        }
    }
```

The app checks whether settings require admin access and prompts user to restart as admin when required. To restart the app I run this:

```
 if (!IsRunAsAdmin())
        {
            // Launch itself as administrator
            ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo();
            proc.UseShellExecute = true;
            proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            proc.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath;
            proc.Verb = "runas";
            proc.Arguments = "RunAsAdmin";

            try
            {

                Process.Start(proc);
                System.Environment.Exit(2);

                return true;

            }
            catch
            {
                // The user refused the elevation.
                // Do nothing and return directly ...
                return false;
            }
```

The problem is a new instance starts but is closed because of the mutex. Then when I close the original instance I get this:

[image: null reference error]

So I was thinking I could pass an argument to the running instance to tell it to allow a new one to spawn, then close the original. Trouble is I cant figure out how to make this work.

Any help would be very much appreciated :)

p.s. I am a C# novice

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to simply destroy your mutex prior to restarting your application:

```
mutex.Dispose();
```

Comment: The mutex is invoked in Program which is not public so currently cannot access it from the class that is trying to restart as admin. is it ok to make it public from Program?

Comment: I tried making it public but it says "code is not heuristically unreachable"

Comment: Program.singleInstance.Dispose();